# getting org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OLE2NotOfficeXmlFileException after updating to xmlbeans 3.1.0

Tags: java, apache-poi, xmlbeans

Recently I have upgraded my xmlbeans jar to version 3.1.0 and poi jars to 4.1.1 version.
After updating the jars I am able to open xlsx file but i am not able to open xls files.

I am using following code to open those files

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(fis);
reader = new XSSFReader(pkg);
```

Previously i used xmlbeans 2.3.0 version with poi 3.1.7 jars

Comment: `OPCPackage ` and `XSSFReader` never could handling `*.xls` files. Both are for `Office Open XML` files only (`*.xlsx`). Same for `xmlbeans` as this only is for handling `XML`. Files named `*.xls` should be in binary `BIFF` format, or more general in `OLE2` format. Neither `OPCPackage ` and `XSSFReader` nor `xmlbeans` has something to do with that.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)